# CollectionProperty - change item's index

Tags: python

I can get an item in my CollectionProperty using index. Like this:

```
item = context.scene.my_collection_prop[index]
```

But how to change the item's index?
I want to put the item into index=0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `my_collection_prop.move(item_index, target_index)`, it let's you place a collection item (specified via its index in the current collection) to an arbitrary position in the collection.

In a collection with 3 items, you would call `move(2, 0)`, to put the last item on top of the list. The other two items remain in order, there's no swapping of the source and target item:

```
import bpy

bpy.types.Scene.coll = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup)
coll = bpy.context.scene.coll
coll.clear() # in case you re-run this script, empty the collection

# item 0
item = coll.add()
item.name = "First"

# item 1
item = coll.add()
item.name = "Second"

# item 2
item = coll.add()
item.name = "Third"

print("Before:")
for i, item in enumerate(coll, 1):
    print("{}. {}".format(i, item.name))

coll.move(2, 0)

print()
print("After:")
for i, item in enumerate(coll, 1):
    print("{}. {}".format(i, item.name))

"""
Before:
1. First
2. Second
3. Third

After:
1. Third
2. First
3. Second
"""
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange that add() and move() methods are not documented in blender python api.

Comment: The methods belong to the class `bpy_prop_collection_idprop`, which is somewhat an internal type and does indeed not appear anywhere in the documentation. If you register a collection property however, you may call `dir(…)` on an instance (if registered on `bpy.types.Scene`, for example `bpy.context.scene`) to see all properties and methods: `['__doc__', 'add', 'clear', 'move', 'remove']`.