# Documentation for CollectionProperty (CRUD methods)

Tags: python, scripting

I cannot find any documentation for the existing `CollectionProperty` methods.

Regardings properties, generally i find [.../bpy.props.html](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.props.html) helpful, but it doesn't have any method declarations.
Usually with other properties this isn't necessary, as they just give me a value of a regular python type that I know - like StringProperty which yields a string.

With a CollectionProperty this is different: it gives me some sort of collection, I can iterate over it, but it is not a simple python structure.
There is the official doc of [.../bpy.types.CollectionProperty.html](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.CollectionProperty.html), but it lacks documentation for the `add` and `remove` methods (it never mentions them).

Related Question:
[Remove from CollectionProperty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/remove-from-collectionproperty)

Apparently there is also a `move` method:
[CollectionProperty - change item's index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23623/collectionproperty-change-items-index?rq=1)

Are there anydocs out there?

P.S. digging through the blender source (of some cloned repo, because I like browsign github) I found this:
https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_props.c#L3029

However I cannot find any hints in there with respect to the existing methods.

Comment: nah, pardon my french but the example is rather weak. It doesn't show how to remove things from the collection, or how to add already existing instance ...

Comment: Bloody French.  [This one sums it up well too](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30446/15543)  Also using autocomplete in py console.  There is no argument that the docs are a little lacking.

Comment: thx, but that still doesn't show me, how to add an element to a collectionproperty that already exists - I can only call the add() method and Blender will create some new instance. Also: do you really have to iterate over the whole list to clear it? ... That's not exactly a nice api, if that is all ... isn't there at least a place in the source code that somehow shows me, what methods are really exposed on that type?

Comment: Consider. `collection.clear()` may not have been available at the time of writing that answer.  IMO a  question like _"How to copy a collection item?"_, or something with _CRUD_ in the title...  would be a far more productive route than bemoaning  _"The docs aren't perfect"_

Comment: The documentation is open source too. Submit a patch or ask something we can solve @IARI

Comment: I found the docs very useful in some respects and had wrongly assumed, that it was just a matter of looking in the right place.
Also my apologies, the question seems to get across too much negativity, which was not the intent, and i'll edit it to get rid of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the documentation. The [Python Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html) is your friend here. It offers autocomplete "intellisense" when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> after a `.` or a `(`:

[image]

You get the methods documentation from the source if there is one. In CollectionProperty case there is none:

[image]

The traceback error gives another hint:

[image]

If this does not help you search [google](https://www.google.com/), [this site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/) or your favorite blender python blogs for the functions you are interested in for more info or code examples. Since you now know what is available and what you are after, this should give better results than searching just for documentation.

If that still fails, chances are that you are after something only couple of people in the world know. You can look into the [source code](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/tree/master/source/blender) where you find [bpy_props.c](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_props.c) and then you dig. If you don't get too far the best bet in this case is to contact developers on official channels ([mail, IRC](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Contact)) and ask there.

Comment: Docs to me are the last resort for when I can't nut it out with the console.  Nice when there are [good docs (example)](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) tho.

Comment: I haden't used the Blender-builtin console, since I generally prefer to write code in a single place, but I will check that out. seems like a very good solution to the problem of the lack of proper docs.

Comment: with your post and some more google I have found this:
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html